# Extract Tweets for Academic Research

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

I am planning to create an academic paper and I need to scrape data from Twitter. However, I am unsure of the authenticity of the data gathered through snscrape and can't afford to pay Twitter API. Is snscrape a valid data-gathering method? What other options can I have?

I tried snscrape but I am unsure of its authenticity. I also tried tweepy but it need authenthication key but I can't afford it.

Comment: What about snscrape makes you doubt the "authenticity" of the data it gathers? If you mean the ethical aspect of scraping, this isn't the place for such a question.

Comment: The financial aspect is also out of scope for this site. You're only options currently are to scrape the site (captchas may interfere), access an API (Twitter's or a third party), or find a cache of archived data.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am concerned if the data is biased or if it is not widely accepted as a data-gathering method for academic papers. Fortunately, I found 4 published articles that used snscrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already used SnScrape to extract tweets for a paper. It was a good scrapper, the only downside was the inability to extract native retweets. But SnScrappe is not working because of Twitter blocks. Currently is not possible to search tweets without a login. As one can see here: https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/996